# When I click on the link with remote: true, not that initializes the plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my `application.js` I have the initialization of `.select2` selects:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".select2").select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true
   });
});
```

In another part of my application I have a link with `remote: true`, which renders a new form with a dropdown with `.select2`:

```
<%= link_to 'new form' new_feed_item_path, class: 'new-feed-item', remote: true %>
```

That as a response loads the partial: `new.js.erb`

```
$('.feed-content').html("<%= j(render 'form', feed_item: @feed_item) %>");
```

But the select doesn't work if loaded this way. Why?
Do I have to initialize the js again?
I don't use `turbolinks` in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the block that initializes the select inside the `new.js.erb` also, because the `$(document).ready` event isn't triggered when you receive a javascript response from the server, only when you have a reload or navigation. To avoid bugging your other selects you should also destroy all before reinitializing, the code would be something like this:

```
$('.feed-content').html("<%= j(render 'form', feed_item: @feed_item) %>");
$(".select2").select2("destroy");
$(".select2").select2({
  theme: "bootstrap",
  width: '100%',
  allowClear: true
 });
```

Comment: I know this method but I believe it's not the best.

Comment: Well, you could use `$(document).ajaxComplete` instead of document ready, but you have no other option but reinitialize it.

Comment: I already understood this. This way is not very convenient.But there's no other way.